# Coping formula downward but changing reference to column as oppose to row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've googled and found references to arrayformulas, offsets, and transposes. It looks like transpose just flips an existing range or data? Arrayformulas was beyond my comprehension. I tried offset, but without any luck. I'm not sure I inserted it right within the existing formula or not.

I just want to increment the column reference as oppose to the row reference when dragging a cell formula down a column to copy it.

I locked the row reference so it no longer increments it, but now I just get the same formula down 20 rows.

On sheet Weekly Top 3s, in cell C4 I have the following formula:

`=if('Weekly Averages'!D$63>0,'Weekly Averages'!D$63,"")`

I want to drag downward and increment the D from D to W throughout the 20 rows. I could do it manually but I will have similar formulas across at least 6 different columns, down 20 rows each.

I would think this is a common issue. It would be nice if I could just utilize a different symbol (maybe ^ as opposed to $) that indicated lock the row, but increment the column.

Anyway, if there is a simple workaround, I'd appreciate any input.

Thanks

Edited: Adding an image to show what I am doing now.
[Weekly Averages tab, each column is a week(1,2, etc). I added the last 3 values in each row to represent top 3 averages that week. This way I can transpose each row. 63 for tops, 64 for 2nds and 65 for 3rds.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0YPB.png)

Now to figure out how to grab the names dynamically without editing a bunch of formulas. Wish me luck :)

Comment: You may need `INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: I’ll come back with a more complete answer later today if I can but I’d recommend looking into using the `BYCOL()` function wrapped in a `TRANSPOSE()` function to output the result of the bycol in a column instead of a row. Here’s a great BYCOL tutorial -> https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/bycol-function/

Comment: @LaravelNewbie can you also provide an example of the sheet you’re working with and the desired output?

Comment: I think I may be looking at this wrong. Maybe I'm not looking for a formula at all. Cause I'm not looking to convert/transpose and existing range/row of cells into a column of cells. I have a single cell who's formula `=if('Weekly Averages'!D$63>0,'Weekly Averages'!D$63,"")` I wish to copy/paste into 19 other cells below it, changing only the "D" reference, to E, F, G, H, I ... W. I'm guessing there isn't syntax/markdown symbol to increment by column as oppose to row when copying downwards. My best bet might be to just convert my x/y axis so that they match the weekly averages direction. :(

Comment: So I short cutted it. On the weekly averages tab I added 6 rows at the bottom and populated them with 1)top scores, 2)2nd scores, 3)3rd scores, 4)top shooter names, 5)2nd shooter names, and 6)3rd shooter names based upon easily copied formulas. That way I have them all listed in their own rows for which I can then transpose back on the Weekly Top 3s tab.